# How to convert this header files to pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is my header files Vector.h I build it in this way but lecturer said that you must do it with pointer. Otherwise program will be crash if I enter some values, so I have to do it with pointer it should be *vector instead of array. I need your help guys.

```
#include <string>
class Vector
{
public:
explicit Vector();
explicit Vector(int);
explicit Vector(int,int);
int getSize();
int getIncrementSize();
void add(int);
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& , const Vector& );
//Vector operator<<(Vector);
Vector operator+(Vector);
int operator[](int);
int getElementAt(int);
void setElementAt(int,int);
void insertElementAt(int,int);
void removeElementAt(int);
void removeElement(int);
private:
int initialSize;
int vector[1000];   
int incrementSize;
int realincrementSize;
int x;
};
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you didn't say to your lecturer, "I'm sorry, could you explain that to me"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

> `int vector[1000];`,

you can declare your 'vector` as

> `int* vector;`.

Now to allocate some memory to `vector`, do

> `vector = (int*) malloc( 1000 * sizeof(int) ) ;`.

Do not forget to do, `free( vector ) ;` when you don't need `vector` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

He probably meant for the row `int vector[1000];`, if you want to create a array you also will have to reallocate manually the memory for be able to add more than 1000 elements.

So replace this row with something like `std::vector myVector;`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are supposed to create a [dynamic array](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).

Your line `int vector[1000];` should be `int *vector;` in that case. Follow the link and then ask specific questions when you have actually tried to make it work.